# If watts exceeds rating?

Tags: power-supply, dc, watts

I have been reading quite a lot on the subject in the past hour and I don't seem to be getting an answer, just about amps. I have a 2 watt rated ball valve, and I have a 12v dc 1 amp power supply. W = a * V. So 12 watts power supply? Would it burn out the ball valve?

Comment: That is just voltage and amperage ratings, I want to know how they combine from the wattage. It doesn't answer that

Comment: The amount of power required depends on the load. Your job is to simply provide a power supply that can provide enough power at the device's rated voltage. P=VI, right? So at the rated voltage, the electrical requirement can be described in either Amps or Watts. Whichever value you have, you can easily calculate the other one.

Comment: What is the voltage of the ball valve? You need to match voltage so if it isn’t 12 volt, forget using that power supply. Assuming it is 12 volt, 2 Watts = (2/12) = 0.17 amps. If you read the linked answer, you know that the power supply amperage must equal or exceed the load amperage. Your 1 amp power supply is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use another example: I have a 100 W light bulb that I'm going to plug into the Irish national grid which has a capacity of 5 GW at peak capacity. Do you think it will burn out my bulb?

Answer: No. The bulb will draw the current it requires. This current is limited by the resistance of the bulb filament.

Back to your question:

> I have a 2 watt rated ball valve, 
>   and I have a 12v dc 1 amp power supply. W = a * V. So 12 watts power supply? Would it burn out the ball valve?

No. It will provide as much power as the solenoid valve requires. The current (and therefore the power) will be limited by the solenoid resistance.